# How do I create a filter for content displayed using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a film review site, where all of the content is generated on the main page from data input in the admin panel and placed into a container div.

I've got a basic sorting system (by ID, ascending/descending) already which works fine on my end, but I also want to be able to filter the films by genre (e.g if film is marked as Action on database, make all non-action films hidden.

This cannot be done by CSS alone as I'm not able to add classes to the content within the containers, the container for the film image is generated via JS.

I'm assuming I need to create a new function such as

```
 function getFilmListByGenre(genreName)
```

Or something along those lines, but I don't know how I'd make it work.

Here is the current Javascript that I have, which creates the sort feature.

```
      let db = new PouchDB('films');

  let radios = document.getElementsByName("sort");
  radios[0].addEventListener("change", getFilmList);
  radios[1].addEventListener("change", getFilmList);

  getFilmList();

  function getFilmList(){
    db.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: radios[0].checked}).then(function(films){

      let listContents = '';


      for(let i = 0; i < films.total_rows; i++) {
        let thisFilm = films.rows[i].doc;
        let image = '<a class="btn" href="viewFilm.html?id=' + thisFilm._id +'"><img class="filmImage" src="' + thisFilm.image +'"></a>';


        listContents += '<div class="filmRow">'+ image + '</div>';
      }

      document.getElementById('filmContainer').innerHTML = listContents;

    })
  }
```

**I basically want to grab the value for genre (which can only be "Action", "Comedy", "Horror" or "Other") for each film from the database, then if the corresponding radio (named filter) is selected, all of the films which aren't labelled as that genre are hidden.**

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', georgia, arial;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-align: left;
}

.sortFilms {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff6699;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 5px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #aaaaaa;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.newFilm {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff6699;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

label {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.form {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  color: #B2365F;
}

#formTitle {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.col {
  padding: 20px;
}

input,
textarea, select {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing:border-box; }
}


.tagline {
  margin: 0;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #000;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  color: #000;
}

#modifyFilmButton {
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row  {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }

  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }

  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }

  table tr {
    border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  table td {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
  }

  table td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.oldFilm {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px;
}

#oldTitle {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #ff6699;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
thead {
  background: #ff6699;
}

.reviewImage {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.filmRow img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 420px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.filmRow {
 -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#filmContainer {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#date {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
}

#date input {
  width: auto;
}

#date label {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}

#oldTitle2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #ff6699;
}

.genre {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
}

.genre input {
  width:auto;
}

.genre label {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
```

```html
    <div class="sortFilms">
    <h2 id="formTitle">Latest reviews</h2>
    <div id='filmContainer'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="oldFilm">
    <h2 id="oldTitle2">Sort by</h2>
      <div id="date">
      <p><b>Age of review</b></p>
      <label>Newer<input type="radio" name="sort" checked/></label>
      <label>Older<input type="radio" name="sort"/></label>
  </div>
  <div class="genre">
  <p><b>Genre</b></p>
  <label>Action<input type="radio" name="filter"/></label>
  <label>Comedy<input type="radio" name="filter"/></label>
  <label>Horror<input type="radio" name="filter"/></label>
  <label>Other<input type="radio" name="filter"/></label>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate your display logic and your fetching logic, then you can just filter out the results that aren't the genre you wanted.  I would do it something like this:

```js
var db = {
    allDocs: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => resolve([{genre: 'Horror', title: 'The Hills Have Eyes'}, {genre: 'Comedy', title: 'Dumb and Dumber'}]))
    }
}
function getFilmList() {
  return db.allDocs();
}

function getFilmsByGenre(genre) {
    return getFilmList().then(films => films.filter(film => film.genre === genre));
}

function displayFilms(films) {
  let listContents = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < films.length; i++) {
    let thisFilm = films[i].title;
    listContents += '<div class="filmRow">'+ thisFilm + '</div>';
  }
  document.getElementById('filmContainer').innerHTML = listContents;
}

document.getElementById('all').addEventListener('click', () => {
    getFilmList().then(displayFilms)
})

document.querySelectorAll('[name="filter"]').forEach(radio => radio.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    getFilmsByGenre(event.target.parentNode.textContent).then(displayFilms)
}))
```

```html
<div id="filmContainer"></div>

<button id="all">All</button>

<label>Action<input type="radio" name="filter"/></label>
<label>Comedy<input type="radio" name="filter"/></label>
<label>Horror<input type="radio" name="filter"/></label>
<label>Other<input type="radio" name="filter"/></label>
```

Comment: How do I go about linking the options to the radio checkboxes I have? Sorry I'm completely hopeless at all of this haha

Comment: see edit - changed the select to radios to show how you could do it